# Variable prop preferredSize of allotment does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, panel

I would like to make a draggable split panel for an editor. Its behavior is mainly like `Console` panel of CodeSandbox:

1. When we click on `Console`, the panel is expanded, and the arrow becomes `ArrowDown` for closing.
2. The border of the panel is dragabble.
3. When we click on `Console` on an expanded panel, the panel is closed, and the arrow becomes `ArrowUp` for expanding.

I have the following code (https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-ydhy97?file=/src/App.js:0-927) by https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment. The problem is that the prop `preferredSize` does not change following `this.state.toExpand`.

Does anyone know why this does not work?

```
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toExpand: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Allotment vertical>
            <Allotment.Pane>Main Area</Allotment.Pane>
            <Allotment.Pane preferredSize={this.state.toExpand ? "0%" : "50%"}>
              <div
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({ toExpand: !this.state.toExpand });
                }}
              >
                Console &nbsp;
                {this.state.toExpand ? "ArrowUp" : "ArrowDown"}
              </div>
            </Allotment.Pane>
          </Allotment>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the prop preferredSize does not change following this.state.toExpand.

This is not the problem, it does change, however, the [documentation](https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment#preferredsize) states:

> Allotment will attempt to use this size when adding this pane (including on initial mount) as well as when a user double clicks a sash, or the reset method is called on the Allotment instance.

It is not configured to update when the prop is changed, however, if you double click on the border after setting it to ArrowDown, it will reset to 50%.

Instead, if you add a reference to the Allotment element by first initializing a reference in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.allotment = React.createRef();

  this.state = {
    toExpand: true
  };
}
```

And assigning it as a prop:

```
<Allotment vertical ref={this.allotment}>
```

Then you can add a callback to the setState for when you change the expand option that calls the reset function:

```
resetAllotment() {
  if (this.allotment.current) {
    this.allotment.current.reset();
  }
}
// ...
this.setState({ toExpand: !this.state.toExpand }, () => this.resetAllotment());
```

**Side-note**, it appears that the Allotment component does not have time to process the new prop change, before reset is called in the setState callback... which is illogical to me, however, you can work around this by a [hacky setTimeout of 0ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful):

```
resetAllotment() {
  setTimeout(() => this.allotment.current && this.allotment.current.reset(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But with your solution, the arrows are not correct: https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-h58266?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: @SoftTimur I have updated my answer, see the **side-note**.